# Create an array from input array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.1, sql-function

I am working on creating a PostgreSQL function. I have a situation where I receive an array as input and I want to use that array and get some other column for each element from that array and convert that into another array maintaining the same order. I have tried below, but I have some issues while executing it.

Below is the Example of what I need: (Let us say `input_array` is the input array to the function)

Example:

```
FOREACH item IN ARRAY $1
  LOOP
    tempVar = (select some_column from some_table where some_other_column = cast(item as varchar));
    some_other_array :=  array_append(some_other_array, tempVar);
  END LOOP;
```

But using the above approach I am not able to get the expected array as output. Somehow the values are not as expected with the above approach. And i am not able to debug whats going wrong in here as well as i cant see the Raise notices in console :(

Any other suggestions on this are highly appreciated.

Comment: Describe what is wrong with the result you are have for now. BTW your example could be rewritten without loop: `some_other_array := array_agg(some_column order by ord) from some_table join unnest(input_array) with ordinality as a(val, ord) on (some_other_column = a.val::varchar);`

Comment: @Abelisto updated the question. Is there any tool that shows raise notice in console for sql function?

Comment: [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) is one of such tools. Also check [`client_min_messages`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES) parameter: `show client_min_messages;` Set it to `info` value if it have higher level: `set client_min_message to info;` It is however  per-session setting. You can set it permanently in the `postgresql.conf` file.

Comment: Do you see any thing wrong in my implementation? I am not able to understand why is it not working @Abelisto Also as per your suggestion i am having a bit of hard time understanding the alternate solution suggested by you. I want to maintain the same order as input array. So not sure what will this do : "order by ord/with ordinality as a(val, ord) "

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 has been [out of support](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for two years now. You should really plan the upgrade to a supported version (e.g. 10) as soon as possible.

Comment: You don't need a loop at all. You can replace the loop with `select array_agg(some_column)
  into some_other_array
from some_table
where some_other_column = any($1);` But to get a good answer you should show us your **complete** function (to do that, [edit] the question, do not post code in comments)

Comment: @ging 1) Your approach seems good (except that it could be simplified to single query like my suggestion in the first comment). And I not understand the meaning of sentence "_Somehow the values are not as expected with the above approach_" Probably you should to provide the examples of expected and actual results. 2) `unnest(..) with ordinality` returns two columns: value and the index of value. You can simply test it using for instance `select * from unnest(array[2,3,1]) with ordinality as a(val,ord);` And using `order by ...` i some aggregate functions you are able to specify the order.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "_you should show us your **complete** function_" Not sure that it is good idea. IMO [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is much better. In addition when creating MCVE people usually find their own mistakes by themselves.